# is there any html element without any style?

Tags: html

`<div>`s have a block display model.

`<span>`s have an inline display model.

Is there any element without any presentation purpose, whose unique goal would be to group other elements ?

Comment: Why not use `div`s or `span`s and then alter the display via CSS?

Comment: `div` and `span` are the logical containers. You could see the basic css settings for webkit [here](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While `<div>` and `<span>` elements as well as newer semantic elements such as `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<footer>`, `<header>`, `<main>`, `<nav>`, `<section>` etc. fulfill the purpose of grouping, they all come with default user agent styles.

Though it is possible to override these styles as needed, the nesting of elements within the DOM tree itself may have undesired effects. For instance, when using `display: flex;` on a parent element, the rendering of its immediate child elements (`>`) is influenced by this.

The new CSS `display: contents;` property value is intended to solve this issue:

> display: contents causes an element's children to appear as if they were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element itself. This can be useful when a wrapper element should be ignored when using CSS grid or similar layout techniques.

Yet, the browser support is not as good as one would hope by the end of 2020:

https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents

Further details on how the implementation **should** work in detail can be found in the spec:

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#valdef-display-contents

Comment: `display: contents` support is now very good (2022); however it still has accessibility issues

Answer (score 14):

No. Every element must have a value for the `display` property. CSS doesn't allow for the possibility of a null value.

`<div>` and `<span>` are the generic grouping elements, and there are numerous non-generic grouping elements. You just have to select the right one for the context (which depends on the markup and semantics involved, not the default value of `display`).

Comment: Correct, even unknown HTML tags have a display property: http://jsfiddle.net/yDDjH/

Comment: While eight years later it is still valid that an elements display property value can not be null, the new `display: contents;` addresses this - see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64952600/1510754

Answer (score 12):

Well - at least with CSS3 you can control it better, e.g. in your div

```
style="all:unset;"
```

This can be used to the same effect as a reset style sheet.

Comment: Yep. I don't remember exactly why I was asking this, but I think it was related to a need to group `<li>` elements (kinda like `tbody`) for table rows.

Comment: One of the most useful CSS answers on the web!!!

Answer (score 5):

`div` and `span` has no semantic meaning; they are made exactly for the purpose of grouping elements.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no elements used for grouping any kind of visual elements.

You can use the `<thead>`, `<tfoot>` and `<tbody>` elements to group `<tr>` elements in a table.